# Is there a way of replacing object pointed to by a shared_ptr without changing the value of the pointer itself?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

In my code I have an application which contains a state manager and a list of the applications possible states. When creating the different states I want to pass to it a list of commands (following the command pattern) that, when executed, changes the state managers current state to the state specified when the command object was created.

This means that when creating a state object, I pass in a list of `shared_ptr<Command>`s, all of which contains a `shared_ptr<ApplicationState>`, and one of the command pointers would contain a pointer to the `ApplicationState` object the list was passed to as constructor argument.

To achieve this I have tried creating the list of `shared_ptr<Command>`s by first allocating space for the `ApplicationState` objects using `std::allocate_shared<ApplicationState>()`, so the pointer for the `ApplicationState` is created, and the state object initialized by its default constructor. I can then pass the list of commands to the state constructor using `reset(new ApplicationState(commandstochangestate, otherargs))` on the already created `shared_ptr<ApplicationState>`. Now the `ApplicationState` object contains a list of commands, one of which contains a pointer to the same `ApplicationState` with all the data initialized by the parameterized constructor.

At least that is the plan, but apparently the functions I use doesn't work as I thought. After using the `reset()` function on the allocated `ApplicationState` objects the `Command` objects still point to empty objects, and throws an exception when executed as they are trying to use the uninitialized members. The finished state objects do however exist alongside the empty ones.

The code in practice looks like this:

```
// Create allocators for allocating the state objects

std::allocator<MainState> allocator_main;
std::allocator<ExtraState> allocator_extra;

// Allocate pointers for _states
// The states allocated here are of type MainState and ExtraState, dummy classes for now, but they
// both inherit from the class ApplicationState

_states[size_t(State::main)] = std::allocate_shared<MainState>(allocator_main);
_states[size_t(State::extra)] = std::allocate_shared<ExtraState>(allocator_extra);

// List of command objects is created

std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<ICommand>[size_t(State::count)]> changestatecommands( new 
    std::shared_ptr<ICommand>[size_t(State::count)], 
    std::default_delete<std::shared_ptr<ICommand>[]>()
);

// Here the command objects are created, the std::shared_pointer to the state objects are passed in
// as the second argument. _states is an array of type 
// std::shared_ptr<ApplicationState>[State::count] (State::count is 2)

changestatecommands[size_t(State::main)] = std::make_shared<StCmdActivate>(_statemanager, _states[size_t(State::main)]);  // StCmdActivate is a child class of Command that sends the specified state to the statemanager, which changes its active state to that state
changestatecommands[size_t(State::extra)] = std::make_shared<StCmdActivate>(_statemanager, _states[size_t(State::extra)]);

// Here I want to replace the objects pointed to by the pointers held by the command objects,
// but instead new pointers are created, and the command objects still point to the empty shells

_states[size_t(State::main)].reset(new MainState(changestatecommands, _window->inputhandler()));
_states[size_t(State::extra)].reset(new ExtraState(changestatecommands, _window->inputhandler()));

// When the command to change the current state to State::main is executed, an exception is thrown 
// because it passes an empty state object to the statemanager

changestatecommands[size_t(State::main)]->execute();
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible at all? If so, how do I do it properly? If not how should I achieve the same functionality in another way? I want each state object to hold all commands that changes the state.

Comment: When you invoke `reset` in a shared pointer, you change the value of the pointer itself, not the value of the object pointed to. It is hard to tell what you try to achieve, because the example is not complete, you might try to write [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help to analyze your problem. From what I see now, you have the circular dependency between your State and Command - this must be clarified, because (1) `shared_ptr` might leak memory in this case, (2) I am not able to tell which entity should be created first.